# When to use collection vs shard?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am little bit confuse in shard and collection. We can make a index a new table to new shard and can be done same as a collection.

> When to make a new shard and When make a new collection.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298435/understing-some-concepts-of-apache-solr/35299919#35299919

Comment: it's not duplicate. in your link those are just meaning here i am more focus on collection vs shard mainly in solr version 4 >

Comment: They are not the same concept. A collection is a collection of _shards_ that represent your whole index. If you want to expand your collection across more servers, create / split a new shard and move it around. The Rebalancing API might be helpful for that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection is a complete logical index in a SolrCloud cluster. e.g you might have three different collections called users,books,people.

On a Logical level the whole index is called a collection. which might be spread over many nodes in the cluster.

A shard is a slice of that whole collection. i.e a collection is made of one or more shards.

> When to use collection ?

`Generally, users will create multiple Collections to separate logical units of data that will not be intermingled, similar to a database in the relational world. Collections are generally isolated from one another and do not typically communicate with each other. Also each Collections will each have their own unique schema.xml to define the types for their index.`

> When to use a shard?

`If you feel your index is too big to be stored on one node . it can be divided into different shards and can be stored on different nodes on a cluster.`

Read more about it here : https://thinkbiganalytics.com/solrcloud-terminology/

Comment: can we make difffrent schema in a shards

Comment: no. shard of the same collection will share the same schema. however Collections will each have their own unique schema.xml to define the types for their index.